# how to use both Cdetailview and grid view in yii view and to export that page to pdf and excel

Tags: php, yii

I have view page with both detailview and gridview 
the grid view should be automatically  filltered by detailview datas.one important thing is detail view model and gridview model are not same they should taken from different models and i didnt assign any relation so all needs to be manul.
and also the view should be exported to pdf and excel view.

my view.php is

```
   <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
    'id',
    'invoice_no',
    'invoice_date',
    'dc_no',
    'dc_date',
    'client',
    'total_amount',
    'status',
),
)); ?>

   <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'invoice-transaction-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    //'invoice_id',
//'invoice_no',
    'dc_no',
    'client',
   /*array(
    'name'=>'client',
        'value'=>'Client::model()->findByPk($data->client)->Client_name',

   'filter'=>CHtml::listData(Client::model()->findall(),'Client_id','Client_name'),
    ),*/
    'project',
     /*array(
        'name'  => 'project',
        'value' => 'Project::model()->findByPk($data->project)->proj_name',
   'filter'=>CHtml::listData(Project::model()->findall(),'proj_id','proj_name'),
        ),*/
    'complexity',
  /*array(
        'name'  => 'complexity',
        'value' => 'Complexity::model()->findByPk($data->complexity)->Complexity_Name',

   'filter'=>CHtml::listData(Complexity::model()->findall(),'id','Complexity_Name'),
        ),*/
    'totalpage',
    'rate_per_page',
    'total_amount',

    /*array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),*/
),
     )); ?>
```

i need to display the grid automatically filtered by the detailed view data ('invoice_no',) 
my controller for the above view

```
public function actionView($id)
{
 //$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('InvoiceTransaction');


    $dataProvider=new InvoiceTransaction('search');//this is a different model
    $dataProvider->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['InvoiceTransaction']))
        $dataProvider->attributes=$_GET['InvoiceTransaction'];
    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

how to solve my problem..anyone can give suggest

**ANSWER** hi i got answer for filtering questioni just added default filter value in my controller

```
public function actionView($id)
{
 //$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('InvoiceTransaction');
     $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    $dataProvider=new InvoiceTransaction('search');
    $dataProvider->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['InvoiceTransaction']))
        $dataProvider->attributes=$_GET['InvoiceTransaction'];
        $dataProvider->invoice_no=$model->invoice_no;/// this line only gave me answer

 //$model->unsetAttributes(); 
      if(isset($_GET['InvoiceMaster']))
        $dataProvider->attributes=$_GET['InvoiceMaster'];
    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$model,'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

but now struggling to export this both detailview and gridview  on same file to pdf or excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) can create Excel documents and export them to PDF. Some [examples can be found here](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples).

Comment: there is no documentation can you help with some examples

Comment: What do you mean, "no documentation"? The documentation is in the download archive... I've updated the answer with a link to some official examples, and feeding "phpexcel examples" to google will probably provide a lot more.

Comment: hi i need one more help how could i used sql to load grid now the problem is the row values are showing the id as stored table i need to retrive corresponding id value from other table.

Comment: used code is '$connection=Yii::app()->db;
$sqlst="SELECT project,complexity,totalpage,rate_per_page,total_amount  FROM Invoice_Transaction WHERE invoice_no='$model->invoice_no' ";
  $command = $connection->createCommand($sqlst);
//$command->bindParam(":book_id",$ids,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $dataReader=$command->queryAll();          
  //$command->execute();'         '$rowID = 8;
foreach($dataReader as $rowArray) {
   $columnID = 'A';
   foreach($rowArray as $columnValue) {$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($columnID.$rowID, $columnValue);
      $columnID++;
   }
   $rowID++;
}'

Comment: You should post that as a question.

Answer (score 1):

This extension [PHPExcel](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/phpexcel) can help you export a gridview to excel file easily.

Comment: there is no documentation can you help with some examples